# How to get Closing Inventory Qty right - DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I can't find the right results for Closing Inventory, given the scenario below:

Measure added to Matrix Table:

```
Calculation= 
VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ) )
VAR curDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( HelperTable[ID] ),
        1, IF ( curDate = minDate, [OpenInventoryMeasure], BLANK () ),
        2, IF ( curDate > minDate, [ProdMeasure], BLANK () ),
        3, [QtySalesMeasure],
        4, if (curDate > minDate,[Closing Inventory], BLANK())
    )
```

Here are the measures created and used in the main calculation above:

```
OpenInventoryMeasure = 
    VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ) )
    VAR curDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
return
CALCULATE(Sum('Production'[Qty]),FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Date] = minDate))
```

```
ProdMeasure =
VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ) )
VAR curDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
return
CALCULATE(Sum('Production'[Value]),FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Date] > minDate))
```

```
QtySalesMeasure = SUM(PedItens[QTDUND])
```

```
ClosingMeasure = [OpenInventoryMeasure ] + [ProdMeasure] - [QtySalesMeasure]
```

Main issue: Right now, Closing measure is not giving me the right result, although the measure that make it up are correct.
Tiny issue: Also, the order is not right in the table, although I had ordered it by ID.

Here's a screenshot of the resulting table:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Opening Inventory measure, because when you do the CALCULATE you are now on the context of the Monday, so it's already filtered by Monday and then you're adding an additional filter of date = 7th which returns blank.

You need to clear the filters first and then apply the date filter:

```
OpenInventoryMeasure = 
    VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ) )
return
CALCULATE(Sum('Production'[Qty]), ALLSELECTED('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date] = minDate)
```

Your Prod measure probably suffers from the same error, but I don't understand what's the logic behind it because you only filter based on min date and not on current date.

Comment: Saw it yesterday. Will try it asap. Thanks a bunch, for instance!